# Visual Studio Load Test w/o Agents - Manually Executing and Aggregating Results

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing

My team recently adopted Visual Studio's Web Performance Test/Load Testing solution. Our test plans are developed, and we preparing to begin collecting baseline performance and stress test results against an corporate MVC application.

Due to corporate network security "features", Microsoft's Agents/Controller on-premises test distribution solution is not an option. Furthermore, the TFS Virtual Lab and Azure Virtual Lab load test distribution solutions are also not viable options due to security infrastructure and resource limitations.

Because of these constraints, it seems our only option is to run a Visual Studio Load Test from each developer machine (at a coordinated time, through different internet connections). *If anyone has another solution, I'm certainly receptive.

Assuming we take this approach, I'm concerned the results Visual Studio stores in the "LoadTest2010" SQL repository will not accurately reflect the combined results of all developer machine's Load Test.

My questions are:

- Is this approach even viable?
- If so, what is the best way to combine the separate Load Test SQL repositories into a single SQL Database (keeping in mind connecting to a central SQL Server during test execution is not an option)?
- Assuming we import all the testers' results into a central database, does anyone have an idea of how to report on composite test results? I'm assuming they'll all have different TestRunIds which seems that would break Microsoft's built in Views and Stored Procedures for analyzing test results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting all the test runs into one database can be done by exporting the results from all the secondary places and importing them into one database. Use the `Open and manage load test results` commands. See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/14503/6752 for more details.

Combining the results from several runs cannot be done, as far as I know, within Visual Studio. However each "graph" can be exported to Excel where you can manually merge the results. The rows of each "table" (but, unfortunately, not the headers) can be copied and pasted into Excel.

I prefer the `Export graph data to Excel` and `Export graph data to text (.csv)` commands over the `Create Excel report`. (The two `Export...` commands are not available for tables.) The reason being that the "Create Excel report" requires Visual Studio to be run as an Administrator and I have not found a sensible way of letting the Administrator user have access to my non-Administrator load test database.